# SQL Server SUM, but aggregating by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm using the following SQL query to sum all payment types from my projects:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(E2_SALDO) as SUM,
    E2_ITEMD as PROJECT,
    E2_ZFORPG AS TYPE 
FROM 
    SE2010 
WHERE 
    D_E_L_E_T_ = ''
    AND E2_NUM BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' 
    AND E2_PREFIXO BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZ' 
    AND E2_NATUREZ BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_VENCREA BETWEEN '20140901' AND '20140915'
    AND E2_PORTADO BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_FORNECE BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_EMISSAO BETWEEN '20000101' AND '20201231'
    AND E2_ZFORPG BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_ZTPED BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_SALDO> 0  and E2_TIPO<>'PR' AND E2_ITEMD BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' 
GROUP BY 
    E2_ITEMD, E2_ZFORPG
```

My result looks like this

```
SUM         PROJECT    TYPE
-----------------------------
848,15      F140319               
7296,36     H1008       DOC          
14534,02    H1008       TED          
36041,33    K0104       BOL       
11127,91    F140363     CAM       
84841,43    H1008       CAM       
500                     CHQ       
1600        K0309       CHQ       
4124,91                 DEB       
200         F130702     DOC       
3394,64     H1001       DOC       
7674,54     H1001       TED
```

That's almost it, but I want to "combine" some results, for example I want all costs for projects starting with "H" to be together, like this:

```
SUM         PROJECT      TYPE
------------------------------
10691       H1001,H1008   DOC       
22208,56    H1001,H1008   TED       
84841,43    H1008         CAM
```

So, in this example, it grouped all `DOC` payment types for everything on "H" projects (1st line), grouped all "TED" payment types (2nd line) and also show projects alone when there is no other project (3rd line, because there is no "H1001 CAM" anywhere)

If possible, I would like to manually inform somewhere the group types, because sometimes I want to have "H" and "K" projects together, so I would like to inform the "groups" in a ( ) , like in a "WHERE TYPE IN ("first","second")

Thank you!

Edit: Running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: You'll need a subquery with `STUFF`/`FOR XML PATH`.

Comment: Do you really have a column named `D_E_L_E_T_`?. Also, what you want to do depends heavily on the RDBMS that you are using (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgresql, etc)

Comment: sorry to tell, I´m using MS SQL Server 2008 R2... and the D_E_L_E_T_ column is to mark if the row is logically deleted (it´s from my ERP)

Comment: Curious.  What do the lines like: `AND E2_NUM BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' ` do?  Do you actually have values outside that range?

Comment: yes. they are "filters". actually this query comes from the ERP, I am rewriting it to get finer results, because today the users are doing manual filters on Excel

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUM(E2_SALDO) AS sum,
    E2_ITEMD =
    STUFF((
        SELECT
            ', ' + E2_ITEMD
        FROM
            SE2010 b
        WHERE
            b.E2_ITEMD = a.E2_ITEMD 
            AND b.E2_ITEMD LIKE '['+@yourProjectNameStartCharacters + ']%'-- H if only starting with H, HK if you want starting with h and k
        FOR xml PATH ('')), 1, 2, ''),
    E2_ZFORPG 
FROM
    SE2010
WHERE
    D_E_L_E_T_ = ''
    AND E2_NUM BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_PREFIXO BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZ'
    AND E2_NATUREZ BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_VENCREA BETWEEN '20140901' AND '20140915'
    AND E2_PORTADO BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_FORNECE BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_EMISSAO BETWEEN '20000101' AND '20201231'
    AND E2_ZFORPG BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_ZTPED BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_SALDO > 0
    AND E2_TIPO <> 'PR'
    AND E2_ITEMD BETWEEN '' AND 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'
    AND E2_ITEMD LIKE '['+@yourProjectNameStartCharacters + ']%'-- H if only starting with H, HK if you want starting with h and k
GROUP BY
    E2_ZFORPG
```